# unused variable 'i' pylint(unused-variable)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I,m using a for loop in the function,
and pass the list in this function
then plint(unused-variable)warning is show
and they do not gave the proper output

```
def ff(f):
      for i in f:
         print (fruits)

fruits=["apple","banana","cherry"]
ff(fruits)
```

`=> unused variable 'i' pylint(unused-variable)`

Comment: It is not used. Do you want to print the things in the list instead?

Comment: In fact, you're not using the `i` variable, pylint might be right this time...

Comment: You could use `_` to tell pylint that it's unused.

Comment: I presume you want `for fruit in fruits: print(fruit)` rather than print all of the list 3 times

Comment: BTW  what does "they do not gave the proper output" mean? You mean your code doesn't do what you want? Or you expected something different from pylint?

Answer (score 13):

As Pylint states, you aren't using the `i` variable.

If you really plan on not using it, change it to `_` and Pylint should ignore it.

```
def ff(f):
  for _ in f:
     print(fruits)

fruits=["apple","banana","cherry"]
ff(fruits)
```

But I think what you want is:

```
def ff(f):
  for fruit in f:
     print(fruit)

fruits=["apple","banana","cherry"]
ff(fruits)
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to print everything in your list, and avoid the pylint warning, print the stuff in the list:

```
def ff(f):
  for stuff in f:
     print (stuff)

fruits=["apple","banana","cherry"]

ff(fruits)
```

---

*Extra details:*

When you say

```
  for i in f:
     print (fruits)
```

you have not used the variable `i`. 
This means your loop prints the whole list of `fruits` for every item in fruit, hence the warning.
When you say

```
  for stuff in f:
     print (stuff)
```

you have used the loop variable name inside the loop, and will print the stuff in the list, one at a time.

Comment: why this, when we use ( i )they show error and use this string they do not show error

Comment: You could put `i` instead of `stuff`. It seems odd to loop over something and ignore this, which is what the error is about. What is the purpose of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this :

```
def ff(f):
 for i in f:
   print (i , end = " ")

fruits=["apple","banana","cherry"]

ff(fruits)
```

output :

```
apple banana cherry
```

Comment: print (i , end = " " )  SyntexError : invalid Syntax                                                                                                                 .                   ^

Comment: brother there is nothing wrong in code. end is used to omit the line change between every print statement